# Check which jRadioButtons have been selected if they have been created in a loop

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jradiobutton

I have a loop that creates rows, where each row has another loop to create 6 JRadioButtons.

Only one JRadioButton can be selected from each row (as it should be), but I'm finding it difficult to use Action Listeners to check whether the correct JRadioButton has been selected from each row, and then change an empty JLabel to show "correct", but I think that will be simple once I've managed the first part.

This is the relevant code I'm working with:

```
    //loop for making flow layout for each line of random letters
    //counter for having number of the row next to each row in order of selection
    int counter = x;
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        //new jpanel created for every row needed for the word
        JPanel jpLine = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

        //new jlabel made with counter number for each row
        JLabel count = new JLabel(Integer.toString(counter));
        jpLine.add(count);
        counter--;
        //random number from 0-5 generated for each row
        Random number = new Random();
        int low = 0;
        int high = 5;
        int ranNumber = number.nextInt((high - low) + low);

        //buttongroup outside loop so only one button can be pressed for each row
        ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();

        //get selected button's index in any group with bg.getSelection().getActionCommand()
        final int row = i;
        final ButtonGroup btnG = bg;
        ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {



                System.out.println("row " + row);
                System.out.println("btn " + btnG.getSelection().getActionCommand());



            }
        };

        //loop for making the number of letters in each row - always going to be 6 letters to choose from in each row
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            //if the random number generated for each row equals the loop
            //then new radiobutton will be created for the ith letter of the reversed
            //answer, starting from charAt 0 and going to the last character
            if(ranNumber == j)
            {
                JRadioButton answerLetter = new JRadioButton("<html><font color = 'white'>" + answerForGrid.charAt(i) + "</font></html>");

                bg.add(answerLetter);
                answerLetter.setBackground(Color.decode("#566771"));
                answerLetter.setOpaque(true);
                jpLine.add(answerLetter);

                //use setActionCommand("" + j) on each button to associate each button with its index
                answerLetter.setActionCommand("" + j);
                answerLetter.addActionListener(listener);
            }

            //ranLetter is generated randomly from the alphabet string, so random letters are
            //created for each jradiobutton
            final String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            final int N = alphabet.length();

            Random letter = new Random();
            char ranLetter;

            while(true) 
            {
                ranLetter = alphabet.charAt(letter.nextInt(N));
                break;
            }

            JRadioButton k = new JRadioButton("<html><font color = 'white'>" + ranLetter + "</font></html>");

            bg.add(k);
            k.setBackground(Color.decode("#566771"));
            k.setOpaque(true);
            jpLine.add(k);
        }
        //add each row of letters (jpLine) to this loops jpanel
        jpCenterCenter.add(jpLine);
    }
```

Also, the correct JRadioButtons I'm looking to be checked are the ones that are created in the if(ranNumber == j) section.

Sorry if I've dragged on but I've found this difficult to explain, so hopefully someone will be able to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `setActionCommand("" + j)` on each button to associate each button with its index, and then get the selected button's index in any group with `bg.getSelection().getActionCommand()`. You can then assign a single ActionListener to all the buttons in one group, and make sure the action listener knows which row it's attached to.

```
// in your "i" loop
final int row = i; // must be final to be used inside the anonymous class
final ButtonGroup btnG = bg;
final String answerAction = "" + ranNumber; // hard to tell if this is what you mean
ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("row " + row);
    String selectedAction = btnG.getSelection().getActionCommand();
    System.out.println("btn " + selection);
    boolean isCorrectForThisRow = (answerAction == selectedAction);
    System.out.println("is correct: " + isCorrectForThisRow);
  }
};
// in your "j" loop, with either the answerLetter or k buttons
// as required
k.setActionCommand("" + j);
k.addActionListener(listener);
```

As it stands, there is a lot to your sample that doesn't quite make sense, so it's hard to suggest more than this (for example - a `while(true)` loop that breaks on it's first iteration). But `setActionCommand` is meant to be used ([oracle tutorial here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)) in exactly this way to find out which button is checked in a button group.

Comment: Thank you that was very clear, one more question though, since I'm very new still to ActionListeners, how can i create a boolean that is true when all 6 correct JRadioButtons have been selected inside the ActionPerformed section? it doesn't have to be a boolean but that's where my thought process is taking me.

Comment: @AEkon. I would say that's a follow-up question so I would recommend you update your code and then [ask a new question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19457/where-should-i-post-follow-up-questions?lq=1). Questions here are [free, as in beer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gratis_versus_libre#.22Free_beer.22_vs_.22free_speech.22_distinction).